# Changing boolean value in Rails 3 app yields ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, boolean

In my Rails 3.0.5 app I have columns on my Profile model for privacy. In each User's settings, I want the user to be able to change their settings so they can determine which parts of their profile are shown. In my migration I added four `boolean` attributes for this. However when I try to update the value (switch between true/false) I get an ArgumentError:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
  app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:162:in `edit_settings'
```

An example of the params passed:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0uySkgRNsIIQSX6PtXl3e0e+MXCTo4yuoU/QjuBxENw=",
 "show_hometown"=>"1"}
```

Here is the boolean in my migration:

```
t.boolean :show_hometown, :default => true
```

Here is the controller action `edit_settings` I'm using to update. There are four `if` statements to update_attribute, but for length I'm only including two:

```
def edit_settings
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.update_attribute(:show_hometown)
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Updated user information successfully.'
  else
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
  end
  ...
  if @profile.update_attribute(:show_current_location)
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Updated user information successfully.'
  else
    redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
  end
end
```

And the form for updating `:show_hometown`:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "edit_settings", :controller => "profiles"}, :html => {:multipart => true }) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag :show_hometown %>
  <%= @user.profile.hometown %>
<% end %>
```

**FOLLOW-UP:**

If I use validations on :show_hometown and insert the following into my controller I can see the value toggle:

```
def edit_settings
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.show_hometown == true
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => false)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  elsif @profile.show_hometown == false
    if @profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => true)
      redirect_to settings_path
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, :notice => 'Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.'
    end
  end
end
```

However, since I have four booleans where I'll apply the same code is there a way to handle each update in one controller action? Or do I need to create a separate action for each boolean attribute I want to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) the column and the value:

```
@profile.update_attribute(:show_hometown, params[:show_hometown])
```

This means set the value of column `show_hometown` to the value in `params[:show_hometown]`.

Note that with `update_attribute` validations are skipped. If you want validations to run, you have to use [`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes):

```
@profile.update_attributes(:show_hometown => params[:show_hometown])
```

To answer your follow-up: with `update_attributes` you can update several columns in one call:

```
@profile.update_attributes({:show_hometown => !@profile.show_hometown,
                            :show_birthdate => !@profile.show_birthdate})
```

There is also a [`toggle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle) method, but using that would result in 4 database calls instead of 1. It *can* be written in one line:

```
%w{show_hometown show_birthdate}.each { |attr| @profile.toggle(attr) }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a quick follow-up based on some of your earlier code that I pasted as an update. I'd appreciate your feedback if you don't mind.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your follow up. You *can* do it in one call, but since your are toggling the values and I assume you don't want to toggle the values of all the columns every time. You can do it in one controller action, but you have to pass which column you want to update via `params`. In you original question you have a checkbox. Why don't you update the values based on what is in the checkbox instead of toggling?

Comment: Thanks Mischa! I'll read this over and try to digest it, but I very much appreciate your help and explanation.